# The matrix has a rank $r$ if and only if $A$ is the sum of $r$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be $m\times n$ matrix.

Show that $\text{rank}A=r$ if and only if $A=\mathbf{w_1}\mathbf{v_1}^T+\dots+\mathbf{w_r}\mathbf{v_r}^T$ where $\mathbf{w}_j$ are linearly independent column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $\mathbf{v}_i$ are linearly independent column vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I was able to show the direction $\Rightarrow$ quite easily.

But how to show the converse? I know that $\text{rank}(A+B)\leq \text{rank}A+\text{rank}B$ then it follows that $\text{rank}A\leq \sum \text{rank}(\mathbf{w}_i\mathbf{v}_i^T)\leq r.$ But how to show that this is exactly $r$?

Would be grateful if someone show the solution, please.

Comment: Without loss of generality, we can assume that the $v_j$'s are normal. If the $v_j$'s are also orthogonal, then we get $Av_j=w_j$ for each $1\leq j\leq r$. Hence, the set $\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_r\}$ is linearly independent, so the rank of $A$ is at least $r$. More generally in the case where the $v_j$'s are not necessarily orthogonal, we have $$Av_j=w_j+\sum_{i\neq j} (v_i\cdot v_j)w_i$$ and I think one can show that these are linearly independent? I haven't worked out details here but maybe this approach works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I worked out my suggested approach; the general approach being that we can show $\{Av_1,\ldots,Av_r\}$ is linearly independent, and thus $rk(A)\geq r$. Combining this with your other inequality will prove $rk(A)=r$.

> So suppose that $\sum_{j=1}^r c_j(Av_j)=0$ for some scalars $c_j$. Note that $$Av_j=\sum_{i=1}^r \langle v_j,v_i\rangle w_i$$ which gives $$0=\sum_{j=1}^rc_j\sum_{i=1}^r\langle v_j,v_i\rangle w_i=\sum_{i=1}^r\left(\sum_{j=1}^r c_j\langle v_j,v_i\rangle\right)w_i.$$ Now linear independence of the $w_i$'s implies $\sum_{j=1}^r c_j\langle v_j,v_i\rangle=0$ for each $1\leq i\leq r$. Hence, $\langle v,v_i\rangle=0$ for each $1\leq i\leq r$, where $v:=\sum_{j=1}^r c_jv_j$ is in the span of the $v_j$'s. Hence, we must have $v=0$, so linear independence of the $v_j$'s implies $c_j=0$ for each $1\leq j\leq r$, and we're done.

Comment: I am quite sleepy and did not think too much but why $Av_j=\sum \limits_{i=1}^{r}\langle v_j,v_i \rangle w_i$? Looks like Gram-Scmidht orthogonalization?!

Comment: By assumption, we have $$A=\sum_{i=1}^r w_iv_i^T$$ so using $\langle v_j,v_i\rangle=v_i^Tv_j$ (or replace transposes with conjugate transposes if you want to do complex vectors) we get $$Av_j=\sum_{i=1}^r w_iv_i^Tv_j=\sum_{i=1}^r w_i\langle v_j,v_i\rangle.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Really nice and simple solution! +1

Comment: Why are you writing $\langle v_j,v_i\rangle=v_i^Tv_j$? I am usually writing $\langle v_j,v_i\rangle=v_j^Tv_i$

Comment: When the vectors are real it doesn't matter which order they're in, but in the complex vector case we need to swap the indices as I do: $\langle v_j,v_i\rangle=v_i^*v_j$. This is because we want conjugate linearity in the second component of the inner product.